Reset system looping and bios ask for password wat should i do any ideas anyone pls help me
Hey anyone who can help me I'm stuck with this help me

Do you know the firmware/BIOS password?  Is this a laptop or Desktop?

Does this answer your question? No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority
